# Android: DoubleTap doesn't work after changing orientation

Tags: android, listener, gesture, ontouchlistener, gesturedetector

I have attached a touchlistener and gesturelistener in my `onCreate()` method.

When I double tap my title bar in portrait mode everything works fine. But when I rotate my screen to landscape mode, the double tap isn't detected anymore. However the Listeners are still being called. And when I rotate my screen back to portrait mode, the double tap works again.

**My Listeners:**

```
 //Add double click gesture listener to Title Bar.
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                myMethod();
                return true;
            }
        });
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Adding `public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e)` works in both orientations

Comment: are you using the method: `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {` ? if so.... are u setting a new contentView? Cause changing orientation restarts activity, so your content title bar is most likely not found anymore

Comment: Please show us some more code

Comment: @Strider Its definately found. as the gesture is still called, and the onclick still fires. as it is attached to the Found titlebar. 

I have noticed that it doesnt matter what i do, it thinks i just long pressed. aka, tap, double click are invoking long press.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought maybe you're switching layouts. But you're not.

Comment: @Strider thanks for edit. Baffled by issue on what causing it :(

Answer (score 2):

Having realised that long click is always invoked, it gave me more scope to finding an existing question/answer.

I found this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177573/gesturedetector-ontoucheventmotionevent-e-calling-onlongpress-on-all-gestures) However, the answer was not relevant in my situation, it did question if I had implemented `OnTouchListener` properly.

Going to the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html) I noticed that I should possibly return true, rather than the gesture result. (`OnLongClick` returns void!) which might have kept forcing it to consume to that result regardless.

Android docs specify an implementation of `OnTouchListener` as follows:

```
View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view); 
myView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // ... Respond to touch events       
        return true;
    }
});
```

**Changing my code to the following fixed the issue**:

```
  //Add double click gesture listener to Title Bar.
  final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
       public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
           myMethod();
           return true;
       }
   });
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
   tv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
           gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
           return true; // ADDED THIS
       } 
  });
```

Why it works in portrait, but not landscape however, I do not know.

Comment: Good that u found a solution.

Comment: @Strider thanks for trying to help :) Still baffled how it works in one orientation. However this fix works in both.